# How to get a specific data from array?

Tags: php, arrays

Right now I have a problem with retrieving data form arrays, maybe it's really simple (probably it is) but I am struggling wiht it since morning and it appears, that my knowledge about PHP is worth nothing...so I have few arrays:

```
array( "name" => "Array 1",
    "type" => "array"),

array( "name" => "Array 2",
    "type" => "whatever"),

array( "name" => "Array 3",
    "type" => "whatever"),

array( "name" => "Array 4",
    "type" => "array"),

array( "name" => "Array 5",
    "type" => "whatever"),
```

What I need to do is to display 'name' of arrays of the 'array' type, I know I need a foreach loop but how to construct 'foreach ($arrays as $array) {' to get the desired result?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the replies, but I tihnk I didn't make myself clear. I need to display "name" only when there is a "type" => "array" present within array, every other arrays' "name" should be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
foreach($arrays as $array) {
    if($array['type'] == 'array') {
        print($array['name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I am already able to do, see Edits in my question please :)

Comment: That should match your "condition"

Answer (score 1):

An [`array_map`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will do

```
array_map(function ($v){ if($v['type']=="array"){echo $v['name']."<br>";}},$arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array 1
Array 4
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124919)

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I am already able to do, see Edits in my question please :)

Comment: I can't choose two answera as appropriate, I used the other one because it was just simpler to add 'if' loop, but yours is good as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

put the arrays into a "container" array first, then you can use that one...

```
<?php

$data = array(

    array( "name" => "Array 1",
        "type" => "array"),

    array( "name" => "Array 2",
        "type" => "whatever"),

    array( "name" => "Array 3",
        "type" => "whatever"),

    array( "name" => "Array 4",
        "type" => "array"),

    array( "name" => "Array 5",
        "type" => "whatever")
);

foreach($data as $array) {
    if($array['type'] == 'array') {
      print($array['name']);
    }
}
```